# Direct peer connection cannot be established in Zerotier

Tags: linux, networking

I have two boxes with ip addresses `10.61.3.88` and `10.170.130.31`. Both are directly accessible to each other and ports 9993 are telnetable. However, neither could see the other in the list of `zerotier-cli listpeers`.

I also tried adding hints to `local.conf` as this

```
    {
            "virtual": {
                    "e4465b2ccc": {
                            "role": "UPSTREAM",
                            "try": [ "10.170.130.31/9993" ]
                    }
            }
    }
```

which doesn't help. All firewalls are turned off and selinux is disabled. One box is Archlinux while the other Centos 7. Zerotier version is 1.2.12.

What's going wrong here?